# How to do the Text Fade wheel animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I wanted to create this type of animation, but I couldn’t find any library. If anyone can suggest any library out there or a method to approach this.

[image: please check this]

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful.

[ListWheelScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html)

Making some minor tweaks you could achieve your requirement easily.

**UPDATE:**

`For fading edges follow this`

[Fading Edge ListView - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066628/fading-edge-listview-flutter)

Comment: And how to achieve that checkmark getting filled after they reach the top?